# Codeigniter : vcf mime type not detected in mac safari

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, vcf-vcard

I am facing problem while uploading vcf file on mac safari.

I have added the vcf required mime types in config/mime.php.

The upload functionality works very well in Mozilla and other browsers but on mac safari it is giving error: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed".

I searched lot but all are saying regarding mime type that I have already added.
I have added following mime type:

'vcf' => array('application/octet-stream','text/x-vcard', 'application/vcard', 'text/anytext', 'text/directory', 'application/x-versit', 'text/x-versit', 'text/x-vcalendar')

Do I need to do some thing extra for mac safari.
Please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: And of course you have set `$config['allowed_types'] = 'vcf';` right?

Comment: Yes, I have added this in my upload function.

Comment: Then it's definitively weird. Can you reproduce it another computer with Safari?

Comment: Do I need to add some different mime type for safari. If so then what will be the mime type that I shall add for safari?

Comment: For me it seem you have the correct mime types. Can you turn on debugging in CI and see what it returns. Also see if you can find out what mime type is reported from Safari.

Comment: have you tried dumping the file on the server on what type it is, because every server handles mime-type differently so even if you set the mime type correctly on your CI it will still return an error because it does not equal to the mime type detected on the server

Comment: Thanks a ton to all of you. Your guidelines did the trick. This mime type was missing text/vcard. I dumped the file on server and it returned this mime type. I added it and now working like charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

You'll need to add the following to /application/config/mimes.php inside the $mimes array.

```
'vcf'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
'vcf'   =>  'text/x-vcard'
```

if don't work try this:

```
'vcf' => 'text/plain'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time and posting here. Yes, I have done it same way. Thanks. But I can't vote up for you because I have only 13 points. Sorry, for that

Comment: Latest version of codeigniter has officially added 'vcf' => 'text/x-vcard'